# Cancelling the Async Task and returning to previous activity on pressing Back Button

Tags: android, android-asynctask, callback

This question has been many times on this forum and I have implemented it using CancelListener on Progress Dialog and it works fine. But there is one problem.When I click back button it returns to previous activity as expected.But when I click on any other part of the screen (ie on the dialog or UI of activity) then also it cancels the dialog and returns to previous activity. How to stop this from happening?

```
 class LoadAllCategories extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    int flag=0;


    public LoadAllCategories(CategoryActivity categoryActivity) {

        OnCancelListener cancelListener=new OnCancelListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0){
                finish();
            }
        };
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CategoryActivity.this);
         pDialog.setMessage("Loading Topics...");
         pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
         pDialog.setCancelable(true);
         pDialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
    }

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        category.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        company.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pDialog.show();
    }
```

This is my onDestroy method killing AsyncTask -

```
 @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {


      if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
      {
         mTask.cancel(true);
       }  

         super.onDestroy();

     }
```

And finally I have also overrided onBackPressed -

```
 @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
            {
                mTask.cancel(true);
            }          
            Intent intent_main = new Intent(CategoryActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            intent_main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent_main);
            finish();

        }
```

Also I want to clarify my doubt that whether onBackpressed needs to be overrided or Cancellistener will do.

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked. I am feeling silly right now to check all the given apis of progressDialog.

Comment: it asking for canseling async task not dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `onBackPress()` and write the code to cancel `asynctask` on it. Befor you do, make sure to write code based on condition, or else, you may not have any way to goback to previous activity.

```
if(asynctaskrunFlag) {
// Code to cancel asynctask
} else {
super.onBackPressed();
} that is,

if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
     {
        mTask.cancel(true);
     } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: That means I have to remove CancelListener on progressDialog?

Comment: You have to remove super.onBackPressed(); for the case when  asynctask is running. That may be your issue.

Comment: what exactly does cancelListener do? Does it also take into count clicks on UI other than Back Button to cancel the dialog?

Comment: Why are you using finish() in public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0){  finish();  }?? it finishes the current activity. You only need to dismiss dialog and stope any work going on in doinbackground() thread.

Comment: ok I will remove finish() from onCancel. But before that I want to know that when exactly onCancel callback is called? On pressing backbutton or pressing anywhere on the screen?

Comment: you can use @Override
 protected void onCancelled() {
  super.onCancelled();
 } method for the asynctask